# Why must you use both glBindBuffer and glBindBufferRange to create a uniform buffer in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

To create a uniform buffer object in OpenGL, why must I call both `glBindBuffer` and `glBindBufferRange`? According to [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Binding_indexed_targets),

> Think of glBindBufferRange as binding the buffer to two places: the particular index and the target​. glBindBuffer only binds to the target​, not the index.

So then `glBindBuffer` seems superfluous to me if you are already binding a buffer to that same target using `glBindBufferRange`.

I am reading Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming and [chapter 7](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Positioning/Tut07%20Shared%20Uniforms.html) shows how to make uniform buffer objects. The code used in the book:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &g_GlobalMatricesUBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, g_GlobalMatricesUBO);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4) * 2, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, g_iGlobalMatricesBindingIndex, g_GlobalMatricesUBO, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4) * 2);
```

This code works until I comment out the call to glBufferData, in which case I get a black screen. This is surprising to me because afterwards we are binding `g_GlobalMatricesUBO` to the `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER` binding target anyways. The documentation linked to earlier also says:

> Do note that this does not replace standard buffer binding with glBindBuffer. It does in fact bind the buffer to the target​ parameter, thus unbinding whatever was bound to that target. But usually when you use glBindBufferRange, you are serious about wanting to use the buffer rather than just modify it.

Which seems to touch on what I'm confused about, but I do not understand this explanation. It says it unbinds whatever was previously bound to the target, which seems to reinforce my (wrong) idea that binding a buffer to the target beforehand is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) does not only initialize the buffer, it creates the buffer object's data store with the specified size. You can think about it like memory allocation in c++.
`glBufferData` creates a data store for the buffer object which is currently bound to the specified target. In this case it creates a data store for the named buffer object `g_GlobalMatricesUBO`, because it is bound to the specified target `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`.

[`glBindBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBufferRange.xhtml) doesn't create any data store, it use the data store which has to exist. The buffer object with the data store is specified by the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I think the question asks about the usage of `glBindBufferRange` vs `glBindBuffer` (not `glBufferData`).

Comment: @BDL From the question: *"This code works until I comment out the call to `glBufferData`"*

Comment: How does this work with the index of the binding point (`g_iGlobalMatricesBindingIndex` in this case)? How does `glBufferData` know to create a data store for the correct index since the index isn't specified until the call to `glBindBufferRange`?

Comment: @DavidDiGioia It doesn't know, it creates a data store for the buffer object wich is currentl bound to the specified target. `g_GlobalMatricesUBO`, is currently bound to the target `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`. `glBindBufferRange` refers to the object `g_GlobalMatricesUBO`.